# Resize a table imported from another TeX file

Tags: input

Is is possible to resize a table imported from another table without having to modify the LaTeX code in the file from which the table is imported? I was thinking of something like:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin = 1.5 cm, tmargin=1.5 cm]{geometry} 

\begin{document}

\scalebox{0.5}{%
    \input{DS}
  }%

\end{document}
```

The table in the file DS.tex looks like the following:

```
\begin{table}[!htpb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
% ...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I got as expected the error : ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

I would like to know whether it is possible to resize the table in DS file without modifying it.

Comment: Yes, did you try it? If you have an error then ask about that error (and supply a test file that demonstrates the problem)

Comment: Note you are missing a `%` after the input, and the file needs top contain a `tabular` not a `table` environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A floating environment (`table`, `figure`, ...) cannot put into an `\hbox` or `\scalebox` that internally uses `\hbox`. However the environment can be redefined locally:

```
\scalebox{0.5}{%
    \renewenvironment{table}[1][]{\ignorespaces}{\unskip}%
    \input{DS}%
    \unskip
}
```

`\ignorespaces` and `\unskip` remove spaces by line ends in the file `DS.tex` that does matter in horizontal mode. An alternative is using `\endlinechar=-1\relax`, but this depends on the contents of the `tabular` environment, because some line ends might not be unwanted (e.g. space between words).

The floating environment can be inserted afterwards, e.g.:

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Table caption}
  \scalebox{...}{...}
\end{table}
```