# centering matlab2tikz tex file in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, matlab2tikz, center, figure-placement

I used matlab2tikz to convert my plot to a tex file and added it into latex but I encountered some problems. Firstly, my plot isn't in the center of the page. How can I tackle this issue? Secondly, how can I change the size of the plot? Is there any option to do this?

[image]

this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
  \usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
  \begin{figure}
  \input{without drug.tex}
  \caption{Performance of cells without drug.}
  \label{fig1}
  \end{figure}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your plot is too wide  to fit in the text width of your page, that's why it overflows into the margin and does not look centred.

Comment: Floats should not be inside `center` environment. Better and correct is `\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{without drug.tex}
\caption{Performance of cells without drug.}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}`.  To your document example try to add `\usepackage{showframe}` to see where image start in the text block and how much protrude out of it. For this amount tra to correct width of the image source.

Comment: As @Zarko said, use ```\centering``` to center the plot, and to scale it use \scalebox as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167208/resize-a-table-imported-from-another-tex-file